I lost my userscripts in Tampermonkey. How do I recover them?
I accidentally moved a file into Tampermonkey's folder inside of %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 4\Local Extension Settings. I moved it out, but when I went to the extensions page, it said that Tampermonkey was corrupted.
I had a lot of userscripts installed. When a Chrome extension is corrupted, there is an option to repair it. I clicked the repair button because I thought that it would look for the problem and replace corrupted files, while keeping the non-corrupted files untouched. Instead, Chrome reinstalled Tampermonkey. I lost all of my userscripts, and I don't remember what they were. I also had one that I was too stupid to just save to my computer. I have no backups. How do I restore my stuff?
(p.s. I posted this here because you can't ask questions on Tampermonkey's website)


I prefer to periodically export all my scripts to a .ZIP file. Later they can all be restored at once.

About a month ago, when I upgraded my Opera browser, I deleted my entire profile. Fortunately, I was able to recover it with a file recovery program (I used R-Studio: https://www.r-studio.com/Data_Recovery_Download.shtml).


